# Walk cycle in oposite direction? How to Flip animation after 180 turn?

Tags: animation

I have animated walk cycle and 180 degree turn , now I want my character to walk in oposite direction without having to create another walk cycle.

I there any way to copy/paste walk cycle after before making a turn and put it after the turn?
Essentially, I want to copy my walk cycle but flipped along x axis.

[image: Start of the animation]

[image: Turn]

[image: Pose after making a turn]

Comment: you should parent your armature to an empty and rotate the empty the way you want, unless you have a precise reason why you need to do what you're asking?

Comment: If you make it's cycle so that it walks in place, then you can just keyframe the master root bone to turn it around, and keep using the existing walk cycle. However, if you animate it through actual space, while keeping your master root bone unanimated and unmoved (such that the subject gets further and further away from the master root bone), then, naturally, you won't be able to do this. And from your second picture, it looks like you may be using the latter approach. I recommend the former.

Comment: My walk cycle is in place but , to avoid slipping, turning makes whole body shift a little bit backward